# How to show the changes after submitting the form

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a field in service (loginService) isLogged, it is a behavoiorSubject

```
public isLogged = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(!!localStorage.getItem('authToken'));
```

When I submit the form on login.component, onSubmit() method works and it change the value of isLogged to true.

```
public onSubmit() {

  if (this.user.valid) {
    this.loginService.isLogged.next(true);
  }
}
```

I want to show the isLogged value in header.component.html so I use async pipe in view but its value doesn't change in header.component.html when I submit the form.

```
<div (click)="loginBtnClick()" routerLink="login"> <span>{{loginService.isLogged | async}}</span></div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please include minimal example code that includes what you've tried. In principle, what you describe should work.

Comment: Sorry I embedded pictures but they are not seen

Comment: Unable to reproduce issue - [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7ac19f?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should define a BehaviorSubject in a separate injectable class(service) after that you have to inject that service to both components whether you want to set value or read value.

Comment: Thank you, I already find solution it is because of lazy loading in my app. I moved the service to coreModule and it works!

Answer (score 0):

- Please do not post code as embedded pictures. If the external service hosting them goes down, your question becomes possibly indecipherable.
- You're attempting to execute statements *after* `router.navigate(...)` which might never be executed. Instead you have 2 options:

  - Trigger `router#navigate` after the statements

  ```js
  this.loginService...;
  this.loginService...;
  this.loginService...;
  this.router.navigate(['../main']);
  ```

  - [`router#navigate`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) function returns a promise. So you could execute the statements in it's `then` block.

  ```js
  this.router.navigate(['../main']).then(() => {
    this.loginService...;
    this.loginService...;
    this.loginService...;
  });
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I already find solution it is because lazy loading in my app. I moved service to coreModule and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, service was provided in the lazy loaded module so it does not act like singleton, so I moved it to coreModule and it works!